# GitLab push error (hook declined)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, gitlab

I'm trying to push my "master" repository from a git remote to another remote that I have created. (the old git remote has a lot of bugs and I cant seem to fix it) When I try to push the master branch i get this error:

```
Writing objects: 100% (1002/1002), 144.73 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1002 (delta 362), reused 1002 (delta 362)
POST git-receive-pack (148344 bytes)
remote: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1:in `require'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To http://192.168.45.92/root/old_git.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://192.168.45.92/root/old_git.
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the follwing which might be pointing to the old remote

## Inside /home/git/repositories

```
rm -rf **/hooks/gitolite-hooked
rm -rf **/hooks/gl-pre-git.hub-sample
rm -rf **/hooks/post-receive.mirrorpush
```

Comment: which one? root/old_git is the new remote, where I'm trying to push everything to.(its the destination)

Comment: Delete the above files in the old remote and give a try.

Comment: I dont have any of those files. All i have is:
applypatch-msg.sample*  post-update.sample*     pre-commit.sample*          pre-push.sample*    update@
commit-msg.sample*      pre-applypatch.sample*  prepare-commit-msg.sample*  pre-rebase.sample*  update.sample*